# How to make Autorest not to generate optional parameters in the extension methods

Tags: c#, swagger, autorest

I've got a swagger json file for the service that specifies a method with a required parameter userName. However, Autorest generates an extension method with this parameter being optional. That causes confusion for the end user because they can call that method not providing anything which will definitely fail.

Autorest generates:

```
public static object GetUserGet(this XyzService operations, string userName = default(string))
```

I want it to generate:

```
public static object GetUserGet(this XyzService operations, string userName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your swagger json set the parameter in question to `"required": true`  that should fix your problem.

Here is an example:

```
    "paths": {
    "/api/Search": {
        "get": {
            "tags": [ "Search" ],
            "summary": "Get all cars in a given location",
            "operationId": "Search_GetByLocation",
            "consumes": [],
            "produces": [ "application/json", "text/json", "text/html" ],
            "parameters": [
                {
                    "name": "location",
                    "in": "query",
                    "description": "SoFL= 26.16,-80.20",
                    "required": true,
                    "type": "string"
                },
                {
                    "name": "make",
                    "in": "query",
                    "description": "Car make",
                    "required": false,
                    "type": "string"
                }
            ],
            "responses":{ }
        }
    },
    "/api/Stats": {}
},
```

That example is from this API:
http://turoapi.azurewebsites.net/swagger/docs/V1